# Angular js difference between {{::somevalue}} and {{somevalue}}

Tags: angularjs

Hi guys i'm working on a project where i've found different syntax for data binding  {{::somevalue}} and {{somevalue}} ,and have no idea what is the use of one and what is the use of the other, and also could not find anything on google.

I've worked with typescript and used jsrender in the past and remembered that this is the way it binds a model to a view but i don't think there is any connection whatsoever.

EX:

```
<a ng-href="{{::organiser.Phone}}">...</a>
ng-if="::organiser.Email"
```

i mean is there any relevant difference or they can be used interchangeable ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression "An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::` is one time binding ; it is mainly used when we are not changing the value of that variable, for example, heading/header of any page/table which is static text and are not going to change by any other way.

taken from [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

> An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression.
>   One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable,
>   which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a
>   non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).